# Error "; expected" lambda expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, lambda, .net-4.5

When I build the project I am getting error:

> ; expected

at below line (at `=>` symbol). I google the issue but did not found anything.

```
public sealed class SqlError : baseclass
{
    public override string Name => "sql";`  --> Error here
```

Name property in base class is defined as below

```
public virtual string Name { get; }
```

Comment: That would work in VS2015 dunno if its a new feature in VS2015

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I did not meet this construction either in VS 2015 nor in VS2013

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov That is "member bodied expression", new in C# 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn it into

```
public override string Name{
    get{
      return "sql;
    }
}
```

I think its a VS2015 feature

```
public override string Name => "sql";`
```

is the ' in the code aswell, then remove it ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a C# 6.0 feature which I don't think can be used in VS2013. Stick to a normal property override.
It's available in VS2015 if the project has been configured to support C# 6.0.